# dataGridView com quebra de linha, porém ao exportar para excel não quebra

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Galera,

Tenho um dataGridView que utilizei o seguinte trecho de código para quebrar o texto:

```
     dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
     dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

     dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
     dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
     dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
```

No grid está funcionando corretamente, exemplo da string que estou recebendo:

> "Ao sol da manhã\r\n uma gota de orvalho\r\n precioso diamante."

Ao exportar para o excel não quebra texto na "MESMA" celula e sim para a linha de baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código para exportar para Excel

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
       // Qubra de linha
       // xlWorkSheet.Range["B1:B500"].Cells.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].Cells.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth += 15;
        //xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].AutoFit();
        xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].Cells.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].Style.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, 2].Style.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[9, 2].Style.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[10, 2].Style.WrapText = true;
        xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].WrapText = true;
        //Set Text-Wrap for all rows true//
        xlWorkSheet.Rows.WrapText = true;
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
    }
```

Como podem ver ao quebrar texto para excel, o mesmo não é quebrado dentro da mesma célula e sim para novas linhas.
Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Não seria o caso de tirar o `WrapText`?

Comment: `\r\n` vai de fato quebrar a linha para outra célula no excel, Acho que você pode dar um replace por `<br>` ou só por `\n`

Comment: O Excel trabalha com pré-formatação, neste caso você precisa editar a coluna que irá receber esse dado com a opção de "Quebrar texto automaticamente", assim independente de como vier do seu código o mesmo vai respeitas as condições estabelecidas da planilha, ou nesse caso, da coluna.

Comment: @Leandro já tinha tentando com \n, Environment.NewLine;,(char)13 (char)10; nada nenhum funciona. "Igor" Não posso criar planilha antes pq essas planilhas tem de ser criada na hora, não posso ter uma pré-configurada antes.

Answer (score -3):

Só utilizar o metodo replace para substituir o \n por um 
 assim: Replace("\n", "<"br">");